# Angular2 useAsDefault not work for child route

Tags: javascript, angular

I have been playing around with Angular2 route example which has child route as default route, but the example did not navigate to that default route: https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/tutorial/ts/plnkr.html

While the tutorial of Tour of Heroes which has not child route, useAsDefault was working normally: https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/router/ts/plnkr.html

Any sollution would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently nested `useAsDefault`s don't work, I'm not aware of that behavior. Note too that the problem is the `useAsDefault` in the parent route, not in the child.

You can fix that issue though by adding a `redirectTo`.

```
    @RouteConfig([
      { path : '/', redirectTo : ['CrisisCenter'] }, // Here...
      { // Crisis Center child route
        path: '/crisis-center/...',
        name: 'CrisisCenter',
        component: CrisisCenterComponent
      },

      {path: '/heroes',   name: 'Heroes',     component: HeroListComponent},
      {path: '/hero/:id', name: 'HeroDetail', component: HeroDetailComponent},
      {path: '/disaster', name: 'Asteroid', redirectTo: ['./CrisisCenter', 'CrisisDetail', {id:3}]}
    ])
    export class AppComponent { }
```

Note that I removed the extra `useAsDefault`. I'll file an issue so they can fix it in the docs.

**Update 2**

It isn't a mistake in the docs actually, it's a bug. I got the [confirmation](https://github.com/angular/angular.io/issues/646#issuecomment-168852795) by @wardbell. There's already an [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5742) filed for this bug.

So according to his comment the docs won't be updated (there's nothing to update, it's a bug!).

> This issue was reported [...]. I left the doc as is, hoping that it will become correct soon.

**Update**

Here's the [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.io/issues/646) I filed. They'll tell us if it's a mistake in the docs or not (most likely, I'll bet on that). I'll update after they answer.

Comment: thanks. Now it's working ^_^

actually i have tried that redirectTo before but dont know why not work, maybe some typos of mine

Comment: should be ok now. if not, please report it as a bug

Comment: Is this still a bug, or what? I am having this same issue and started looking for answers - found this...please let me know as I would love to avoid the `redirectTo` as that just feels like a hack.